# joomla not installing on Windows 7 ultimate 64Bit

Tags: windows, joomla, installation

I am installing `joomla 2.5` in my computer in 4th step after filling all the information like username, password and database name when i click on next button the process is going continue its not going 5th step. I am using `wamp server` for 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether you have selected right version of Database like Mysql OR Mysqli. For testing you can check the installation with XAMPP. Check for spacing etc while copying details in the relevant fields. HTH :)

Comment: when i am installing the table of joomla is installing in database but component is not installing

Comment: Can you check the installation on XAMPP and let me know the situation?